# LinkedIn login using LinkedinSwift not working suddenly

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, frameworks, linkedin-api

i am using LinkedinSwift last one year but now redirect to app is not working got no valid session error.but browser working fine.any solutions available.thanks in advance.My code is below

```
linkedinHelper.authorizeSuccess({ [unowned self] (lsToken) -> Void in
    self.linkedinHelper.requestURL("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me", requestType: LinkedinSwiftRequestGet, success: { (response) -> Void in
        print("Request success with response: \(response)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            //let data: NSData = response.data.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSData
            do {
                let json = response.jsonObject
                if let dictionaryJson = json as NSDictionary?{

                    print(dictionaryJson)

                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            //                    print(response?.statusCode)
        }
        // self.writeConsoleLine("Request success with response: \(response)")
    }) { [unowned self] (error) -> Void in
        // self.writeConsoleLine("Encounter error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    // self.writeConsoleLine("Login success lsToken: \(lsToken)")
    }, error: { [unowned self] (error) -> Void in

        //  self.writeConsoleLine("Encounter error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }, cancel: { [unowned self] () -> Void in

        // self.writeConsoleLine("User Cancelled!")
})
}
```

Comment: if you can check in link-din website then SDKs of link-din is closed.

Comment: @SagarBhut other solution available for this issue?

Comment: any link available for Linkedin sdk closed information?@SagarBhut

Comment: use that answer may it's Help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkedIn is closed support for SDK from march1,2019 onwards.
Visit https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates

Answer (score 0):

here is simple solution

```
    import UIKit
import LinkedinSwift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let linkedinHelper = LinkedinSwiftHelper(configuration: LinkedinSwiftConfiguration(clientId: "Your client id", clientSecret: "yout clientSecret", state: "DLKDJF46ikMMZADfdfds", permissions: ["r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress"], redirectUrl: "your project or your company any project url"))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        linkedinHelper.authorizeSuccess({ (token) in

            print(token)
            //This token is useful for fetching profile info from LinkedIn server
            self.linkedinHelper.requestURL("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,picture-urls::(original),positions,date-of-birth,phone-numbers,location)?format=json", requestType: LinkedinSwiftRequestGet, success: { (response) -> Void in

                print(response)
                //parse this response which is in the JSON format
                // self.linkedinHelper.logout() //logout session
                 let cookie = HTTPCookie.self
                let cookieJar = HTTPCookieStorage.shared

                for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! {
                    // print(cookie.name+"="+cookie.value)
                    cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
                }
            }) {(error) -> Void in

                print(error.localizedDescription)
                //handle the error
            }

        }, error: { (error) in

            print(error.localizedDescription)
            //show respective error
        }) {
            //show sign in cancelled event
        }

    }

}
```

and add method in Appdelegate

```
import LinkedinSwift   
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        if LinkedinSwiftHelper.shouldHandle(url) {
            return LinkedinSwiftHelper.application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
        }

        return true
    }
```

just need to add pod:-

```
pod 'LinkedinSwift'
```

Comment: error:  2019-01-24 13:01:07.671474+0530 linkedinlogin[662:353705] lisdksession manager  openURL called!,
2019-01-24 13:01:07.671566+0530 linkedinlogin[662:353705] Expires on: (null)
<LSLinkedinToken - accessToken: (null), expireDate: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000>
2019-01-24 13:01:07.678889+0530 linkedinlogin[662:353705] no valid session

Comment: you can add your client id, client secret and redirection url?

Comment: nope its redirect to linked in app and not error no valid session